# getContext() in Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-context

Where can I access `getContext()` in a `Fragment`? I mean, it is not null and can be used (for instance, for controls creation). Is it `onAttach`, `onCreateView` or `onActivityCreated`?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

All the mentioned answers are basically correct. You should get the activity's context between onAttach and onDetach so I like adding this to my fragments:

```
private Context mContext;

@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    mContext = context;
}

@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();
    mContext = null;
}
```

and then whenever I use mContext I add a check:

```
if(mContext != null) {
   //your code that uses Context

}
```

**UPDATE:**

In Support Library 27.1.0 and later, Google has introduced new methods requireContext() and requireActivity() that will return a non null Context or Activty.

If the Fragment is not currently attached at the time of calling the method, it will throw an IllegalStateException: so use within a try catch block.

Comment: Are there cases when mContext is null and a fragment still exists? Or do you mean there is a long-running operation that ends when fragment is detached?

Comment: Yes if there's a long running operation with a callback in the fragment and you've just clicked on a button that switches fragments, so your fragment is no longer attached to your activity.

Comment: Agree, this variant is possible.

Comment: I think, we can use `isAdded()` to determine, whether a fragment still exists. But your variant is better if we rely on context only.

Comment: Currently `requireContext()` and `requireActivity()` are mandatory instead of `getContext()` and `getActivity()`. Your answer is more correct as there are situations when `getContext() == null` in `onCreate()` or `onCreateView()`, according to other topics in StackOverflow.

Answer (score 9):

`getContext()` will always be not null between `onAttach()` and `onDetach()`

Answer (score 2):

Use `getActivity()` between `onAttach` and `onDetach` to get the attached `Activity` which is the `Context` of the `Fragment`.

Comment: I think, it's almost the same. I meant that `getActivity()` or `getContext()` might be used inside a fragment's lifecycle.

Answer (score 1):

You're pretty safe by calling `getContext()` inside `onCreateView()`. If you take a look at the [docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#Lifecycle) you'll see that from `onAttach` onwards your fragment will have a context.

Comment: in onViewCreated(), context may sometimes be null in my project. so same case may occur in onCreateView(). Thus your assumption is wrong.

Comment: @oiyio, it is interesting. I read in some question, that they really had gotten context == null. I understand so, that when a fragment recreates it can be created before an activity. So, can it mean that `onCreateView` is called before `onAttach`?

Comment: It sounds logical. The reason of context is null, may be onCreateView is called before onAttach.